# extending List and its generic

Tags: java, list, generics, extend

I'm trying to do such thing:

```
public class MyClass1 implements IMyInterface{
    public boolean myMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
public class MyClass2 implements IMyInterface{
    public boolean myMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
public class MyList<T extends IMyInterface> extends ArrayList<T>{
    public T getSomething(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            if (get(i).myMethod())
                return get(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I can use it like this

```
public class MyClass3{
    public void doSomething(MyList<IMyInterface> list){
        ...
    }
}
public class MyClass4{
    public MyList<MyClass1> list1;
    public MyList<MyClass2> list2;

    public MyClass4(){
        MyClass3.doSomething(list1);
        MyClass3.doSomething(list2);
    }
}
```

But I getting a error with this message: The method doSomething(MyList) in the type MyClass3 is not applicable for the arguments (MyList)

Comment: Show us your actual code, not some made-up example of what you're intending. The bug is in *actual* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method definition

```
public void doSomething(MyList<IMyInterface> list){
        ...
}
```

says that it will only accept `MyList` of type `IMyInterface`. You cannot pass it a `MyList` of type `MyClass1 or MyClass2`. `MyList<MyClass1>` is a subtype of the raw type `MyList`, but not of the parameterized type `MyList<IMyInterface>`.

You need to use `bounded wildcard type` to deal with situations like this. You need to make the parameter to accept a `MyList` of type `IMyInterface or some subtype of IMyInterface`. So in order to make it work, change the method parameter of `doSomething` to this;

```
public void doSomething(MyList<? extends IMyInterface> list){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [wilcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)

change `doSomething(MyList<IMyInterface> list)` to `doSomething(MyList<? extends IMyInterface> list)`

Answer (score 0):

This signature :

```
public void doSomething(MyList<IMyInterface> list)
```

will match as soon as the arg is a `MyList` of `IMyInterface`.
But in your code you try to call it with a `MyList` of `MyClass1` and this is not the same.

Modify the signature so that it will match all `MyList` of `IMyInterface` and also all `MyList` of subtype of `IMyInterface`. To do that you must use an upper bound widcard like this :

```
public void doSomething(MyList<? extends IMyInterface> list)
```